# Find a bilinear transformation that maps $|z| \leq 1$ to $|w| \geq 3$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

[image]

my question is that on what basis do we choose $z_1, z_2, z_3$ and $w_1, w_2,w_3$?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need to identify $z_1, z_2, z_3$ and $w_1, w_2, w_3$ (which may have been mentioned simply to describe mapping properties of the function) to identify the transformation. $z \mapsto \frac{-3}{z}$ seems to do it.

Comment: so if i chose them arbitrarily I will reach the same mapping?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think the equation is intended to show that the mapping leaves the "cross ratio" invariant, which is separate from the definition of the mapping itself. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio

Comment: well, in these notes, the author to deduce the mapping

Comment: Perhaps it is desired to take $(z_1, z_2, z_3) = (-1, -i, 1)$ and $(w_1, w_2, w_3) = (3,-3i,-3)$. There are lots of ways to come up with fractional linear transformations because they are determined by a small amount of information.

Answer (score 0):

By the **orientation principle** (all Möbius -or bilinear- transformations are orientation preserving), any Möbius transformation that maps
\begin{align*}
z_1=-1&\mapsto w_1=3\\
z_2=-i&\mapsto w_1=-3i\\
z_3=1&\mapsto w_3=-3
\end{align*}
will map the circumference $|z|=1$ into the circumference $|w|=3$, and the left hand side of the orientation $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ (this is, the region $|z|<1$) into the left hand side of the orientation $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ (this is, the region $|w|>3$). Hence, you just need to find a transformation that satisfies the latter.

To find said transformation, recall that, under any transformation $T$, the cross ratio is invariant. This means that, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$,
$$(T(z),T(z_1),T(z_2),T(z_3))=(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)$$
or, calling $w=T(z)$,
$$(w,w_1,w_2,w_3)=(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)$$
This is equivalent to the last equation you have. Therefore, plugging in $z_1=-1$, $w_1=3$, $z_2=-i$, $w_1=-3i$, $z_3=1$, $w_3=-3$ and solving for $w=T(z)$ in terms of $z$ will yield the transformation you are looking for.